# How to properly convert string to list using generator

Tags: python

**Problem description:** I want to create a program which accepts different grades from 1 to 5, devided from each other by `,` . Then it should create list (convert the string to list) where each element is going to be written as follows: `GradeName : Grade` (e.g. `Good : 4`). The program should create a list using a generator. If the Grade is lower than 1 or higher than 5, the element should look as follows: `Error : Grade` (e.g. `Error : 7`)
Grade names should be:

```
1 - under satisfactory
2 - under satisfactory
3 - satisfactory
4 - good 
5 - excellent
```

**Sample input:** 3, 5, 0, 4, 7

**Sample output:** `['satisfactory : 3', 'excellent : 5', 'Error : 0', 'good : 4', 'Error : 7']`

**My solution:**

```
l = str(input("Grades: ")).split(', ')
l_grades = ['Error', 'under satisfactory', 'under satisfactory', 'satisfactory', 'good', 'excellent']
grades = [f'{l_grades[int(l[i])]}: {l[i]}' if l_grades[int(l[i])] != None else f`Error : {l[i]}` for i in range(len(l))]

print(grades)
```

**Output:**

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1c8df1a45fe9> in <module>()
      1 l = str(input("Grades: ")).split(', ')
      2 l_grades = ['Error', 'under satisfactory', 'under satisfactory', 'satisfactory', 'good', 'excellent']
----> 3 grades = [f'{l_grades[int(l[i])]}: {l[i]}' if l_grades[int(l[i])] != None else 'Error' for i in range(len(l))]
      4 print(grades)

<ipython-input-8-1c8df1a45fe9> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 l = str(input("Grades: ")).split(', ')
      2 l_grades = ['Error', 'under satisfactory', 'under satisfactory', 'satisfactory', 'good', 'excellent']
----> 3 grades = [f'{l_grades[int(l[i])]}: {l[i]}' if l_grades[int(l[i])] != None else f`Error : {l[i]}` for i in range(len(l))]
      4 print(grades)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Question:** How to properly define generator, so there would be no such error as mentioned above? I've been trying to tackle this issue for quite a while, but I still cannot figure out how. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You forgot to define the case where grade > 5 or grade < 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
l = str(input("Grades: ")).split(', ')
l = [int(i) for i in l]
l_grades = ['Error', 'under satisfactory', 'under satisfactory', 'satisfactory', 'good', 'excellent']
grades = [f'{l_grades[i]}: {i}' if 0 <= i <= len(l_grades) else f'Error : {i}' for i in l]

print(grades)
```

The grades in `l` correspond exactly to the list indices in `l_grades`, because fortunately `'Error'` is at the 0th position.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you haven't used a generator at all. You could do something like this. I've simplified it slightly to aid your understanding. Create a lookup of grades to results. Then use a generator (using yield) to map those grades to the results.

```
lookup = {
    3: 'satisfactory',
    4: 'good',
    5: 'excellent'
}

grades = [3, 5, 0, 4, 7]

def map_grades(grades):
    for grade in grades:
        result = lookup.get(grade, 'Error')
        yield f'{result}: {grade}'

mapped_grades = list(map_grades(grades))
```

Note that in this case the generator is a bit pointless as it is ultimately converted to a list and isn't aborted. Still, if you really meant generator, this is one!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
l = [int(i) for i in str(input("Grades: ")).split(', ')]

l_grades = {
    1: 'under satisfactory',
    2: 'under satisfactory',
    3: 'satisfactory',
    4: 'good',
    5: 'excellent'
}

grades = [
    f'{l_grades.get(i, "Error")}: {i}'
    for i in l
]

print(grades)
```

Answer (score 0):

As input values can be more than 6(len of l_grades) so you cannot access l_grades[int(l[i])] != None as l[i] can be greater than or equal to len(l_grades) so you are getting IndexError as you are trying to access an element outside the list bound.
You can try this:

```
l = str(input("Grades: ")).split(', ')
l_grades = ['Error', 'under satisfactory', 'under satisfactory', 'satisfactory', 'good', 'excellent']
grades = [f'{l_grades[int(l[i])]}: {l[i]}' if ((int(l[i])<len(l_grades)) and (int(l[i])>=0))  else f'Error : {l[i]}' for i in range(len(l))]
print(grades)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we will going to create a **Dictionary** to contain the grades with its values:

**Code Syntax**

```
Grades = {1: "under satisfactory",
                  2 : "under satisfactory",
                  3 : "satisfactory",
                  4 : "good",
                  5 : "excellent"
                 }
```

Now, we've information with keys for each grade. Let's allow the user to enter the list of values he wants:

```
def user_insertion():
    data = int(input("please, Enter number of grades you want to insert between 1 to 5: "))
  
    for i in range(1, data+1):
        try:
            keys = int(input(f"\nGrade {i}:  "))
            list_of_keys.append(keys)
        except ValueError:
            print ("Please, enter a number not character")
            
    list_of_grades = []  
    for key in list_of_keys:
        if key in  grades.keys():
            list_of_grades.append(f"{grades[key]}: {key}")
        else:
            list_of_grades.append(f"Error: {key}")
    return list_of_grades
```

**Main Execution**

```
print(user_insertion())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
please, Enter number of grades you want to insert between 1 to 5: 5

Grade 1:  1

Grade 2:  3

Grade 3:  5

Grade 4:  9

Grade 5:  t

Please, enter a number not character

['under satisfactory: 1', 'satisfactory: 3', 'excellent: 5', 'Error: 9']

[Program finished]
```